windows 11 regional time settings revert to default
After starting windows 11 for the first time the time was presented like this "9:22 PM" instead of "21:00". I changed the regional settings to 24h and it was OK until I restarted windows. Whenever I start windows the time settings revert to the default AM/PM. Why is this happening and how can I make the change in settings persist after restarting windows?

Have you changed the time format both in Settings and in the Control Panel?


If there are multiple accounts, make that change as Admin as well as users. 2. Does BIOS/UEFI have a separate time format setting?


@harrymc I've changed it in both

@DrMoishe Pippik After changing the format in the admin account it seems to work. I don't know if it's going to change again but if it's really the admin account that matters why do you even get the option to change it if you're not the admin? The BIOS has no time formatting option.
